# Name of the Google compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I am new to Google Cloud Platform and trying to understand it. I have launched a compute engine and have installed a web application. I can access that application using External IP address of the engine or with private IP address from within the VPC.

How can I refer to them with any kind of name?

Just like AWS has this concept of having a name for each instance as ec2-54-54-54-54.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com. So, I can use this name in my browser and with some DNS, this name will be resolved to actual IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Where can i find the name servers of Google Compute Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846900/where-can-i-find-the-name-servers-of-google-compute-engine).

But the answer is that Google Cloud Platform does not provide default public DNS for external IP addresses.

You will need to use `Cloud DNS` or another service or leverage an external service like [xip-io](http://xip.io/) which will map any IP to a DNS name.